# Rails : get field from two table into activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**Table sample:**

users :id, name, email, created_at, update_at
messages : id, user_id, msg, froms, status, created_at, update_at

**In php :**

```
$query = "SELECT messages.id, users.name, users.email, messages.msg, messages.from FROM messages,users WHERE users.id = messages.user_id";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row =$result->fetch_array())
{
  echo $row[0];
  echo $row[1];
  echo $row[2];
  echo $row[3];
  echo $row[5];
}
```

**In rails :**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base 
belongs_to :subject
end
```

**how i use in activerecord ??**

```
@user = User.select("messages.id, users.name, users.email, messages.msg, messages.froms").joins(:messages)

<% @user.each do |user| %>
<%= ???? => ## i don't know for get field 

<% end %>
```

Comment: do `user.email`, `user.name` .. likewise .

Comment: in terminal type "rails console"

Comment: then type these lines
@user = User.select("messages.id, users.name, users.email, messages.msg, messages.froms").joins(:messages)

Comment: then type "@user" in the same console. then you will see the schema of the new active record object

Comment: @AntoDominic you have typo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4289344/anto-dominic). :D

Comment: and if you see the schema to be like "@user(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string);" and you want to display "id" in the code of yours you just need to type <%= user.id %>

Comment: @ArupRakshit ... what typo ? :P I didnt get what you meant

Comment: thanks @arup rakshit, but error if use user.email, user.name in RAILS CONSOLE

Comment: @AntoDominic .....We**d** Development

Comment: if i write in rails console for get field then what i do ?
user = User.select("messages.id, users.name, users.email, messages.msg, messages.froms").joins(:messages)

error if use user.email, user.id in rails console
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting messages with user info
so you should start by message

```
@messages = Message.includes(:user)
```

model

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :name, :email, to: :user, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

view

```
<% @messages.each do |msg| %>
  <%= msg.id %>
  <%= msg.user_name %> #or msg.user.name if ignore delegate in model
  <%= msg.user_email %> #or msg.user.email if ignore delegate in model
  <%= msg.msg %>
  <%= msg.from %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yes i am sorry, i am new and beginner in stackoverflow.com.. thanks @longduong :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query starts from the `User` model, therefore you will get back a list of `User` instances. That means that you can easily access user attributes by using

```
@users = User.select("messages.id, users.name, users.email, messages.msg, messages.froms").joins(:messages)

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

However, if you want to access messages information, that's a little bit more complicated. In fact, as User can have more messages (I suppose), then the best way to fetch them is to run a second query or use `includes(:messages)` rather than `joins(:messages)`.

```
@users = User.select("name, email")

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>

  <% user.messages.each do |message| %>
    <%= message.msg %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```